# ModuleNotFound error while running through Bash

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a Python script 'test.py' which has import pymysql. I have installed pymysql using pip and sudo. When I run this .py, it works great.

I have another Bash script which is used to run the above test.py. When I run this bash script, I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Where am I going wrong?

PyMySQL==0.9.3
Python=3.7.1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that pymysql's location needs to be in your PATH environment variable.

When you run your bash script, what version of python is it using? Is it using the python "on which" you installed pymysql, or another one?

To make sure you are using the correct version of Python, I suggest using venv.

Comment: I noticed that the problem occurs when my bash script is using python3 to run the .py script. if I run it using python, then it works properly. Seems like bash is not using python3. How do I check what version of python is bash using?

Comment: what you can do is run your bash from a virtual environment (venv) to force it to take whichever version of python you need.